# How to optimize this code to reduce execution time?

Tags: python, algorithm, stack

**The question is here:**

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/equal-stacks/problem

**I am getting a termination error due to time out!
Please help me out.**

**Algorithm explanation:**

> **Step I.**

get the 3 array and reverse them, create a new array out of an existing array with each element is sum of all the previous elements. eg: [3,2,1,1,1] -> [1,1,1,2,3] -> [1,2,3,5,8]
So the 3 new array formed would be [1,2,3,5,8] [2,5,9] [1,5,6,7]

> **Step II.**

Again reverse the array [8,5,3,2,1] [9,5,2] [7,6,5,1]

> **Step III.**

Take the smallest array i.e. [9,5,2] traverse the smallest array and search element in the other 2 array - if the element is existing in other 2 array, STOP there and return the number.
Eg. Here I start with elem - 9 : Which is not existing in other 2 array. Next I start with elem - 5 : it is existing in other 2 array. 
Hence the answer is 5.

```
import os
import sys

def equalStacks(h1, h2, h3):
    new_h1=[]
    new_h2=[]
    new_h3=[]
    h1=list(reversed(h1))
    h2=list(reversed(h2))
    h3=list(reversed(h3))
    new_h1.append(h1[0])
    new_h2.append(h2[0])
    new_h3.append(h3[0])
    bol=False
    ans=-1
    for i in range(len(h1)-1):
        new_h1.append(new_h1[i]+h1[i+1])

    for i in range(len(h2)-1):
        new_h2.append(new_h2[i]+h2[i+1])

    for i in range(len(h3)-1):
        new_h3.append(new_h3[i]+h3[i+1])

    low=min([n1,n2,n3])

    if low==n1:
        for i in list(reversed(new_h1)):
            if (i in list(reversed(new_h2))) and (i in list(reversed(new_h3))):
                bol=True
                ans=i
                break
            else:
                pass

    elif low==n2:
        for i in list(reversed(new_h2)):
            if (i in list(reversed(new_h1))) and (i in list(reversed(new_h3))):
                bol=True
                ans=i
                break
            else:
                pass
    else:
        for i in list(reversed(new_h2)):
            if (i in list(reversed(new_h1))) and (i in list(reversed(new_h3))):
                bol=True
                ans=i
                break
            else:
                pass


    if bol==True:
        return(print(i))
    else:
        return(print(0))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    n1N2N3 = input().split()

    n1 = int(n1N2N3[0])

    n2 = int(n1N2N3[1])

    n3 = int(n1N2N3[2])

    h1 = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    h2 = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    h3 = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    result = equalStacks(h1, h2, h3)
```

I am getting a timeout error....please help me to optimize this code.

Comment: Hint: the answer (5) appears in all three lists created in step 1, i.e. Its count is 3.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution with `itertools`:

```
data = '''
3 2 1 1 1
4 3 2
1 1 4 1
'''

from itertools import accumulate, chain, groupby

# prepare the data
data = [[*map(int, line.split())] for line in data.splitlines() if line.strip()]

max_height = 0
for v, g in groupby( sorted(chain(*[accumulate(stack[::-1]) for stack in data]), reverse=True) ):
    if sum(1 for _ in g) == 3:
        max_height = v
        break

print(max_height)
```

Prints:

```
5
```

Answer (score 0):

If the stacks aren't the same height, then at least one is shorter than the tallest one.  The shortest one can't be made taller, so the tallest one must be made shorter.

Pop an item off the tallest stack.

Repeat until they are all the same height.

Comment: yes even I thought of this solution at first but couldn't code it out that effectively and ended up in timeout error for all the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution.

Ping me if you are not able to understand.

Here simply apply greedy approach to remove the minimum height cylinder from stack one by one until we get maximum equal height.

```
def equalStacks(h1, h2, h3):
    h1.reverse()
    h2.reverse()
    h3.reverse()
    i = sum(h1)
    j = sum(h2)
    k = sum(h3)
    while i != 0 or j !=0 or k!= 0:
        x = min(i,j,k)
        if i > x:
            i -= h1.pop()

        if j > x :
            j -= h2.pop()

        if k > x:
            k -= h3.pop()

        if i == j and j == k:
            return i
    return 0
```

Comment: I don't that h1.reverse() method will work. it outputs NONE!

Comment: If you are using python 3.x it will work. You can also use directly                                           h1_new  = list ( h1[ :  :-1]). Both will work.